# Can I Develop custom webparts in VS2013 with a remote site in windows 8.1?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, custom

I have windows 8.1 and wants to develop custom webparts for a remote sharepoint site. Can i do that using visual studio 2013?
I have subscription for sharepoint online portal.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint *Online*, you cannot develop *Web parts*, but "only" add-ins that may contain *App parts*.

App parts are used (instanciated on the page) by end-users like Web parts. However, they're technical completely different.

So, to answer your question: yes, you can develop add-ins and App parts remotely from VS2013 on Windows 8.1. You can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx) to "get started", but there's a lot of other articles on the Internet about developing SharePoint Online add-ins, App parts and how to setup the dev environment.